# How to convert Excel spreadsheet 2007 to pdf in Linux also by updating links

Tags: libreoffice

I have an excel file with a valid =DDE() function.

I want to convert it to PDF using the following command:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf *.xlsx
```

How do I convert to my pdf but I also update my DDE function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LibreOffice 4.2.8.2 420m0(Build:2) (latest aviable unde Ubuntu 14.04).

All the above versions should not allow any update of formula due to security updates, therefore avoiding Excel Comand Injection (which I actually need).